# Конвертация между utf8 и cp1251 с сохранением результата

Tags: c++, utf-8, cp1251

как сменить кодировку utf8 на cp1251 и обратно, чтобы буква 'ю' так и осталась буковой 'ю'? под буквой подразумевал любой символ русской раскладки

Comment: Вы имеете в виду содержимое файла? В linux проще всего вызвать [iconv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv)

Answer (score 1):

Пример использования функций Windows API для преобразования между UTF-8 и CP1251:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

std::string ConvertCP1251ToUTF8(const std::string& str)
{
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, str.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
    wchar_t* wstr = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, str.c_str(), -1, wstr, len);

    len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, -1, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
    char* utf8 = new char[len];
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, -1, utf8, len, 0, 0);

    std::string result(utf8);
    delete[] wstr;
    delete[] utf8;

    return result;
}

std::string ConvertUTF8ToCP1251(const std::string& str)
{
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
    wchar_t* wstr = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), -1, wstr, len);

    len = WideCharToMultiByte(1251, 0, wstr, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    char* cp1251 = new char[len];
    WideCharToMultiByte(1251, 0, wstr, -1, cp1251, len, NULL, NULL);

    std::string result(cp1251);
    delete[] wstr;
    delete[] cp1251;

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); // Установить кодировку консоли UTF-8
    std::string original = "Hello, мир!";
    std::string cp1251 = ConvertUTF8ToCP1251(original);
    std::string utf8 = ConvertCP1251ToUTF8(cp1251);

    std::cout << "Original in UTF-8: " << original << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Converted to CP1251: " << cp1251 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Converted back to UTF-8: " << utf8 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что этот код работает только на Windows, так как использует функции WinAPI для конвертации